# Sobolev spaces exponents on Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the book of Hebey *Non linear Analysis on Manifolds: Sobolev spaces and inequalities*, and I am trying to understand the definition he gave of Sobolev spaces on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (page 21). As long as I understand it, given a function $h\in C^{k}(M)$ we can define its covariant derivative of order $k$ to be the $k$-form defined inductively by
$$
\nabla^0h:=h,
$$
and for $k\geq 1$
$$
(\nabla^k h)_{i_1,\dots,i_k}:=(\nabla_{i_1}h)_{i_2,\dots,i_k},
$$
where with $\nabla_{I}$ I denote the covariant derivative in the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^I}$ direction. This definition makes sense to me, since $Dh=dh$ and $D^2 h=\nabla dh$ which is the classical definition of the Hessian. The problem is the exponent in the definition of the Sobolev $W^{k,p}$ norm of $h$: in this book it is given by
$$
\int_M g(\nabla^kh,\nabla^k h)^p\,dvol.
$$
Here I am trying to use a more compact notation, extending $g$ on the tensors bundle by letting
$$
g(dx^i,dx^j):=g^{ij},
$$
and extending this by linearity, setting naturally
$$
g(S\otimes T,G\otimes Q):=g(S,G)g(T,Q).
$$
What I don't understand is the $p$ exponent: for instance, if $p=2$ this norm does not agree with the norm induced by the inner product
$$
<h,f>_k:=\int_M g(\nabla^kh,\nabla^k f)\,dvol,
$$
even if the author says so in page 22. I am sure I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: It looks like a typo in the book. The expression Hebey gives to be $|\nabla^k u|$ should really be $|\nabla^k u|^2$.

Comment: Thank you, should I put something like $\frac{p}{2}$?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It should be (the $p$th root of) the integral of the $p$th power of the norm, i.e. the $(p/2)$th power of the inner product of $\nabla u$ with itself.

Comment: Hebey's other text, *Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds*, has it right.